# Set time zone from cookie

Tags: python, datetime, http, django, geospatial

Is the `set_cookie` variable the correct way to signal that the cookie should be set? It does not seems pythonic to me:

```
cookie = request.COOKIES.get(TIMEZONE_COOKIE_NAME)
set_cookie = False
if cookie and cookie in pytz.all_timezones_set:
    timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(cookie))
elif request.ip:
    geo = GeoIP2()
    try:
        time_zone = geo.city(request.ip).time_zone
        if time_zone:
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(time_zone))
            set_cookie = True
    except GeoIP2Error:
        self.logger.warning('Could not determine time zone of ip address: %s', request.ip)

response = self.get_response(request)
if set_cookie:
    response.set_cookie(TIMEZONE_COOKIE_NAME, time_zone)
return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Well my previous suggestions don't work with the fact that
`get_response` has to be called with the correct timezone active.

---

- Is the `time_zone` attribute from `GeoIP2` always compatible with
  `pytz` btw.?

Perhaps the following would work, verifying the cookie value only once
and discarding it if it doesn't fit:

```
cookie = request.COOKIES.get(TIMEZONE_COOKIE_NAME)
if cookie not in pytz.all_timezones_set:
    cookie = None

if not cookie and request.ip:
    try:
        cookie = GeoIP2().city(request.ip).time_zone
    except GeoIP2Error:
        self.logger.warning('Could not determine time zone of ip address: %s', request.ip)

if cookie:
    timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(cookie))

response = self.get_response(request)
if cookie:
    response.set_cookie(TIMEZONE_COOKIE_NAME, cookie)
return response
```

So, downside is a lot of mentions of `cookie`, upside is that it's not
more costly what you had before and the call to set the timezone is only
there once.

---

Last point, if anything like this happens to be needed more than once,
put it into separate functions.  This snippet is a bit short to make
that call.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot forgot to mention that get_response **must** be called after the time zone was activated! Otherwise the page would be rendered with the default time zone.

Comment: Right, that changes things :)

Comment: I have exactly your both snippets written before :) With this the cookie is always send with the response, even if it's already set. I know that it is not a big overhead, but my above solution covers it.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you're good with what you have.